# Is this an Aloe kilifiensis?

Tags: identification, succulents, container-gardening, aloe

I was sent this plant labeled 'Aloe kilifiensis'. I looked up some pictures, and didn't seem to find anything even remotely similar. In my eyes it looks more like to Gasteraloe 'Green Gold'.

[image]

Can anyone give me a positive identification?

Comment: Looks more like Gasteraloe to me too - the only place I can find a mention of Aloe kilifiensis is on Ebay; any images concentrate on the brown flowers and not  the leaves. As its Ebay, and I can't find that name anywhere else, I'd disregard the name, its hardly a reliable source, Ebay

Comment: @Bamboo I saw A. kilifiensis listed in Wikipedia, Dave's Garden, and other websites. But all The pictures seem to closer resemble A. zebrina, than the plant I have

Comment: You did better than me then - my search didn't offer Daves or Wikipedia...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seller ID was wrong. This is an intergeneric hybrid between Gasteria and Aloe. I think this is x Gasteraloe 'Green Gold'

[Aloe kilifiensis](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/173537/#b) has a very different form, as a low, wide rosette. It has a wider, longer leaf and is a more robust plant, as well as being considered 'stemless'.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that this looks just like the pictures on the internet.  Why don't you think this is what the label states?  Surely you've seen this site, yes? [aloe kilifiensis images](https://www.google.com/search?q=aloe%20kilifiensis&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&tbm=isch&imgil=1LAgbZV09dCVeM%253A%253Bb5h-xsg4hJVc8M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.arkive.org%25252Faloe%25252Faloe-kilifiensis%25252Fimage-G99204.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=1LAgbZV09dCVeM%253A%252Cb5h-xsg4hJVc8M%252C_&usg=__M12lno9dnyBtFKR3Ilu3xSYZCqw%3D&biw=1600&bih=808&ved=0ahUKEwjI2K-0pq_VAhXhh1QKHVCABOcQyjcIPA&ei=5ut8WcjNFuGP0gLQgJK4Dg#imgrc=1LAgbZV09dCVeM:)

Comment: I am not seeing the resemblance. Kilifiensis is flat, spiny, stemless, with long flat leaves and spotted like A. maculata. What I have has short, fat leaves with small, closely spaced spines, is quickly growing a stem, and the leaves are very short (2-3" about). They just don't look alike, even considering possible environmental differences.

Comment: I am looking at the picture you sent and you are saying it doesn't look like all those images?  A stem?  So that those leaves are on a pedestal?  Interesting.  How about another newer picture?  Glad to hear from you...you must be crazy busy now, right?

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUapf.jpg) you go